# dojo.dijit.Button fires onclick event twice

Tags: dojo

I'm instantiating a dijit button inside a custom widget. That bit all works fine. In widget code I'm binding an onclick event handler but when I click the button the event fires twice. Also a second issue is that it also binds the click event to other buttons in the page that aren't related to the widget. Below is a simplified version I what I have. Can anyone tell me why it's doing that. I've spent the last couple of hours trying to fix it.

The code is below but you can also see it here

This is the html page which instantiates the custom widget
https://github.com/screenm0nkey/dojo/blob/master/widgets/destroy-widget.html

This is the custom widget
https://github.com/screenm0nkey/dojo/blob/master/js/tag/widgets/DestroyWidget/Widget.js

This is the template which contains the nested widget
https://github.com/screenm0nkey/dojo/blob/master/js/tag/widgets/DestroyWidget/templates/template.html

**This is the html inside the widget template;**

```
<div style="border: solid 1px pink">
<h3>${name}</h3>

<div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-attach-point="removeBtn" class="removeBtn">
  click me.
</div>
```

**This is the JavaScript inside the widget which binds the handler;**

```
define('tag/Widget', ['dojo', 'dojo/parser', 'dijit/_Widget', 'dijit/_TemplatedMixin'],

function(d, parser) {

return d.declare('tag.Widget', [dijit._Widget, dijit._TemplatedMixin], {

templateString : d.cache("tag", "/templates/template.html"),
widgetsInTemplate : true,
name : 'no name',
button : 'no button',

postCreate : function() {
  parser.parse(this.domNode);
  this.placeAt(d.byId('authorContainer'));
},

startup : function() {
  dijit.registry.forEach(dojo.hitch(this, function(w) {
    if (w.class === 'removeBtn') {
      this.button = w;
      return;
    }
  }))

  this.button.connect('onclick', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target);
  });
},
```

});
});

**And this is the console output;**

```
<input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_0_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">click me.</span>
```

Comment: Added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/688dZ/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know precisely why you get your problem but I think you might have avoided it if you used a more "Dojo style" way of doing things instead of your current "JQuery style" that uses classes for navigation:

1. Try using the new data-dojo attributes instead of the old dojoType style:

   ```
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" class="remove">
   ```
2. Use explicit attach points to reference inner widgets:

   ```
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
        data-dojo-attach-point="removeBtn"            
        class="remove">
       Click me
   </div>
   ```
3. The attach point will set a property of the main widget. You can access the button through it

   ```
   dojo.connect(this.removeBtn, ...
   ```
4. Use onClick to connect to widgets instead of onclick

   ```
   dojo.connect(this.removeBtn, 'onClick', function(){ ... });
   ```

Comment: Hi missingno, that doesn't work. That's what I tried first after reading the dojo documentation. The attach point is only available as a property of the object which is created for the button but it's not available as a property inside the custom widget, which is where I'm binding the functionality. So referencing this.removeBtn in the postCreate method in the custom widget results in an undefined value.

Comment: Hi missingno, just an update but I tried running through dijit.registry.forEach, getting the button object and using it's connect method to bind the click event and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @screenm0nkey: As long as the button your custom widget is templated and the button is declared inside the template the attachPoint should work correctly. You should try posting a minimal working example at JSFiddle because we can't really guess what small mistake you are actually making.

Comment: there are a couple of reasons that I didn't fiddle it but mainly because I'm using dojo 1.7 with the _TemplatedMixin and secondly becuase I thought it would be a quick answer. I'm going to switch back to 1.6 and see if it does the same thing and then I would have a better idea if's it me or dojo. I will also post links to the fileson my github account so you can see them there. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: widgets inside templates [changed from 1.6 to 1.7](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.7.html). You need to add a new _WidgetsInTemplateMixin mixin instead of using the widgetsInTemplate flag

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't work at at all. In fact it worked less well than using the templatedMixin. I wouldn't insert any html into the page. It was like going backwards when I was already heading that way:) I added the github links. I read a post on the dojo site telling the postee to checkout the source code and see how that does it so I will also do that. I was really excited about working with dojo but so far it's been an average experience.

Comment: uum, the way you said it makes it look like you tried used widgetsintemplate in the place of templatedMixin instead of using it *in addition to* templatedMixin.

Comment: @screenm0nkey: I created a working 1.6 example here: http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/4Rzqb/1/ The only thing you would need to change for 1.7 would be the class declaration part.

Comment: I would kiss you if I could. That works perfectly. Thank you so much. I read that most of my widget development will go in the postCreate method but i noticed you used the startup method. Can you tell me why you put it there?

Comment: Oh thanks ^^. You are right that most things should go in postCreate - I just edited your previous code that used startup and didn't stop to think about it. However, remember that there will be some things from time to time that will only work on startup so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

dijit.form.Button is dispatching the second click event on its internal button input.  Check the [source](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.6.1/form/Button.js#L75).  I couldn't tell you why.

I'd recommend connecting to the [widget's onClick event](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit.form.Button) rather than the DOM event.  missingno's answer describes the setup.

Comment: Hi hurraymapled, thanks for the response. missingno answer unfortunately doesn't work (see post below). As for adding inline javascript into the html template, that's poor practise hence me trying to keep all the JS in the widget. There must be an easy way for me to reference the button object created from inside the custom widget. I just don't know yet how yet. I can hack it using the dijit registry but dojo was built for nesting widgets so there must be an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

use [`data-dojo-attach-event`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/#eventAttachments) to automatically connect a handler for you.

in your javascript, add a function that you want to have called when the button is clicked:

```
// somewhere in your dojo.declare...
remove: function () {
    // do your remove stuff here
},
```

then in your template, you would have some markup like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:remove">
    Remove
</div>
```

what that markup means is that you want to connect the `onClick` of the button to the `remove` function of the widget that owns that template.

as a bonus, the management of this connection is handled for you so you don't need to do anything to have it properly disconnected when your widget is destroyed.  **if** you were to do the `dojo.connect` yourself then you should be storing a reference to the handle returned by `dojo.connect` and doing a `dojo.disconnect` when your widget is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks neonstalwart. That didn't work at all for some reason. Tried various tests but doesn't fire it.

Comment: didn't work for me either, but sounds plausible! I ended up stopping event propagation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32176663/2586761

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem on a maintenance job..

I've ended up stopping event propagation:

```
clickFunction: function(e) {
    // business logic here...
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.event.cancelBubble = true; // IE
},
```

I believe my template (in jade, sorry) is correct:

```
button(data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ToggleButton",
       data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: clickFunction") Text
```

Works for me!